# CKEditor file browser as a TAB on the image dialog

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

A customer has a requirement of the file browser to be a TAB on the CKEditor Image dialog.
I do not like the idea but this is the requirement.

Anyone know some plugin or project trying to achieve the same or even to let me know it this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen   http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_dialog_add_file_browser ?

Try to find on that, may be help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link but no :(
I've been reading the docs for hours and a few days now - about to give up - I haven't found any file browser inside the image dialog - as a tab. Maybe it just does not work.